# ufw allow port from ip address range and deny others

Tags: ufw

I'm using `Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS`

```
root@alexus:~# ufw status verbose
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing), deny (routed)
New profiles: skip

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere
2376/tcp                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
2376/tcp (v6)              ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)

root@alexus:~#
```

I used following rule to allow communication from specific IP to port 9150:

```
root@alexus:~# ufw allow proto tcp from Y.Y.Y.Y to any port 9150
Rule added
root@alexus:~#
```

however, from a remote host I'm able to connect to port 9150:

```
[alexus@wcmisdlin02 Desktop]$ nmap -v X.X.X.X -p 9150 -P0

Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2015-09-28 10:45 EDT
Initiating Parallel DNS resolution of 1 host. at 10:45
Completed Parallel DNS resolution of 1 host. at 10:45, 0.10s elapsed
Initiating Connect Scan at 10:45
Scanning X.X.X.X [1 port]
Discovered open port 9150/tcp on X.X.X.X
Completed Connect Scan at 10:45, 0.11s elapsed (1 total ports)
Nmap scan report for X.X.X.X
Host is up (0.11s latency).
PORT     STATE SERVICE
9150/tcp open  unknown

Read data files from: /usr/bin/../share/nmap
Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.23 seconds
[alexus@wcmisdlin02 Desktop]$
```

How do I configure `ufw` to allow connection to port 9150 from specific IP address/range only and not from others?

*** UPDATE ***

```
root@alexus:~# ufw status verbose
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing), deny (routed)
New profiles: skip

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere
2376/tcp                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere
9150/tcp                   ALLOW IN    Y.Y.Y.Y
9150/tcp                   DENY IN     Anywhere
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
2376/tcp (v6)              ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
9150/tcp (v6)              DENY IN     Anywhere (v6)

root@alexus:~#
```

Comment: your `X.X.X.X` addresses are confusing. Use the real addresses, they come anyway from a private address space and are therefore of no interest to attackers.

Comment: @A.B. Sorry about confusion, `X.X.X.X` is public and route-able address, and so is `Y.Y.Y.Y`.

Comment: Only a shot in the blue, disable port 9150 for all and enable with another rule only for the specific ip address.

Comment: @A.B. I just added second rule, allow only from one IP and deny from anywhere, yet still able to connect to it from 3rd host.

Comment: Give me the output of `ufw status verbose` after adding the rule

Comment: @A.B. I updated my question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29676/discussion-between-a-b-and-alexus).

Comment: If you think that you've found a bug, you should add an answer. **;)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after I remove following rule:

> 22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)

`ufw` starts to netfilter.